# ActiveRecord proper relations for messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I want to learn how to properly configure and use relations in ActiveRecord.

I have models:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :association_foreign_key => :from_user_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => :to_user_id
end
```

Table looks like this:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | from_user_id | to_user_id | content | created_at | status |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1            | 2          | Hi, 2!  | <...>      | red    |
| 2  | 2            | 1          | Hey, 1  | <...>      | red    |
| 3  | 1            | 2          | Whats up| <...>      | sent   |
| ...                                                            |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

How I want to use it:

Controller:

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @inbox = Message.where(:to_user_id => current_user.id).order(:created_at => :desc).group(:from_user_id)
    @outbox = Message.where(:from_user_id => current_user.id).order(:created_at => :desc).group(:to_user_id)
  end
end
```

View usage (THERE IT FAILS BECAUSE MODELS NOT CONNECTED PROPERLY):

```
<% @inbox.each do |i| %>
    <p><a href="/messages/<%=i.id%>"><%= User.find(i.from_user_id).email %></a><%= i.created_at %> <%= i.status %></p>
<% end %>
```

I want to get user details from i. Is it even possible? :) Lets say something like i.user.email

Also it would be cool to access it from user object also. E.g. current_user.messages.inbox (current_user from gem 'devise')

Comment: Check out my solution below to see if it helps you out, @Vygandas

Comment: Cool, I'll check it later today, @franksort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inbox_messages, foreign_key: :to_user_id, class_name: 'Message'
  has_many :outbox_messages, foreign_key: :from_user_id, class_name: 'Message'
end
```

**app/models/message.rb**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_user, foreign_key: :from_user_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :to_user, foreign_key: :to_user_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Now in a `view` you can do (assuming `current_user` from **Devise**:

```
Inbox:

<% current_user.inbox_messages.each do |m| %>
  From <%= m.from_user.email %>
  Status <%= m.status %>
  Content <%= m.content %>
<% end %>

Outbox:

<% current_user.outbox_messages.each do |m| %>
  To <%= m.to_user.email %> <br />
  Status <%= m.status %> <br />
  Content <%= m.content %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: When trying to get inbox messages I get error: Unknown key: association_foreign_key. What could cause this?

Comment: @Vygandas Which version of Rails? (`$ rails --version`)

Comment: @Vygandas Try it with `foreign_key` instead of `association_foreign_key`.  I made the changes above.